WSO2 Micro integrator - status code 413 "request entity too large"
I'm using WSO2 integration studio to create an API.
I have a multipart/form api that uploads a photo, I increased the max request size and response size in the deployment.toml.
When I logged the image content base64 string, i can see that its too long indeed.
I'm getting the below error when I try to execute the api
    {
        "statusCode": 413,
        "message": "request entity too large"
    }

but If I try to execute the same photo directly on the endpoint it returns status code 200 and responds normally.
I have no nginx server in the middle, just the micro integrator directly with the endpoint.
Source code:
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <api context="/v1" name="HealthcareAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/identity/match">
            <inSequence>
                <!-- Log incoming request to debug property extraction -->
                <log level="custom">
                    <property expression="//image/@filename" name="Image Filename"/>
                    <property expression="//image/@content-type" name="Image Content-Type"/>
                    <property expression="//type" name="Type Value"/>
                </log>
                <!-- Set properties for use in payloadFactory -->
                <property expression="//image/@filename" name="filename" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//image/@content-type" name="content_type" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//image" name="content" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//type" name="type" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="base64Encode(get-property('content'))" name="base64ImageContent" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <!-- Log properties to verify they are set -->
                <log level="custom" separator=",">
                    <property expression="get-property('filename')" name="Image Filename Property"/>
                    <property expression="base64Encode(get-property('content'))" name="***** base64 Image content"/>
                    <property expression="get-property('content_type')" name="Image Content-Type Property"/>
                    <property expression="get-property('content')" name="#####Image full Content Property"/>
                    <property expression="get-property('type')" name="Type Property"/>
                </log>
                <!-- Create JSON payload -->
                <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                    <format>
                        {
                            "image": {
                                "filename": "$1",
                                "content_type": "$2",
                                "content":"$3"
                            },
                            "type": "$4"
                        }
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('filename')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('content_type')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('base64ImageContent')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('type')"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <!-- Log the transformed JSON payload -->
                <log level="custom">
                    <property expression="." name="Transformed Payload"/>
                </log>
                <!-- Call the endpoint -->
                <call>
                    <endpoint key="QueryDoctorEP"/>
                </call>
                <!-- Log endpoint call confirmation -->
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="Log Property message" value="API Has been called"/>
                </log>
                <respond/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property expression="get-property('response')" name="Raw Response"/>
                </log>
                <!-- Set response headers explicitly -->
                <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="default" type="STRING" value="*"/>
                <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="default" type="STRING" value="POST, GET"/>
                <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="default" type="STRING" value="content-type"/>
                <property name="Content-Type" scope="default" type="STRING" value="application/json; charset=utf-8"/>
                <!-- Ensure content length is set if needed -->
                <property expression="get-property('Content-Length')" name="Content-Length" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <respond/>
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence>
                <log level="custom" separator=",">
                    <property name="Log Property message" value="&quot;########Failing#########&quot;"/>
                </log>
                <respond/>
            </faultSequence>
        </resource>
    </api>

